# How to escape backslash (\)in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: escaping, google-cloud-dataflow, oracle-adf, backslash

I have to load a CSV file using ADF Data Flow, example data below...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/faYWu.png

How to remove the escape character "" from the PROD_SUBCAT field. I tried using replace function in a DataFlow but its not working. Both PROD_SUBCAT and CREATED_BY are merging into one column. Results are like below...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/50rsJ.png

As you can see above, CREATED_DATE data is moved to the column before. Can you please guide me how to fix this issue? Thanks.